# Open cmd.exe on the computer from an Arduino Uno

Tags: cmd, arduino, get

I am using an Arduino Uno. I want to know whether it is possible to open `cmd.exe` and run `dir /s` when I plug in the Arduino to my PC. This process should be automatic.

Current, I am trying to do this by using `system("cmd")` from my Arduino program, but this doesn't do anything:

```cpp
// Define the button pin
const int buttonPin = 2;

void setup() {
  // Set the button pin as an input
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  // Initialize serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
  system("cmd");
  Serial.println("Arduino Uno is Getting Wifi");

}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                      // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(100); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible from the Arduino code itself. The [`system` function](https://www.codingunit.com/c-reference-stdlib-h-function-system#:%7E:text=CodingUnit%20Programming%20Tutorials-,C%20Reference%20function%20system(),has%20called%20the%20system%20command.) passes the command to the "host environment". On an Arduino, that's the Arduino's microprocessor, not your computer.

Instead, you would need a program running on the computer which will:

1. Automatically detect that there's a new serial port available when the Arduino is connected.
2. Connect to the corresponding serial port and verify it really is the Arduino (and not some other device or serial port).
3. Open a terminal window on the computer and run the commands you'd like to run. (Warning: Avoid running arbitrary commands just because a device you *think* is your Arduino was connected. What if another device was connected that acted just like your Arduino, but sent malicious commands?)

In general, you want to be careful about doing things on the computer only because a device was connected, or based on the fact you *think* the connected device is a trusted device. Always ask yourself: How could someone misuse this capability to do something bad? (Yes, someone could always connect something that looks (to the computer) like a keyboard and do anything the user could do, but it's still important to be aware of the risks.)